# Pass parameter by reference to cmdlet in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to write a simple PowerShell cmdlet in C#  that accepts an instance of ArrayList and adds an item to it.  The issue I've encountered is that a copy of the array list is passed to cmdlet, not the actual object as I would expect. Is there a way to pass parameter by reference? The following code outputs just "Count is 0" for ArrayList $B.

*Note: to run the program in PowerShell 7.1 you need to target .NET 5 and install Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK and System.Management.Automation Nuget packages.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace CustomPowerShellCmdlet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string powerShellScript = @"

$B  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Add-CollectionItem -Collection $B -Item '1'
Add-CollectionItem -Collection $B -Item '2'

Write-Output  ('Count is ' + $B.Count)
            ";


            var output = RunPowerShellScript(powerShellScript);

            foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static Collection<PSObject> RunPowerShellScript(string powerShellScript)
        {
            InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initialSessionState.Commands.Add(new SessionStateCmdletEntry("Add-CollectionItem", typeof(AddCollectionItemCmdlet), null));

            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
            {
                runspace.Open();

                using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Streams.Error.DataAdding += Output_DataAdding;
                    ps.Streams.Debug.DataAdding += Output_DataAdding;
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;

                    ps.AddScript(powerShellScript);

                    return ps.Invoke();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Output_DataAdding(object sender, DataAddingEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ItemAdded.ToString());
        }

        [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "CollectionItem")]
        public class AddCollectionItemCmdlet : Cmdlet
        {
            [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
            [AllowEmptyCollection]
            public ArrayList Collection { get; set; }

            [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
            public object Item { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// This static field is needed for demo purposes only.
            /// </summary>
            public static List<object> AddedItems = new List<object>();

            protected override void BeginProcessing()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A new collection is passed to the cmdlet: {0}", !AddedItems.Any(x => ReferenceEquals(x, Collection)));
                AddedItems.Add(Collection);

                Collection.Add(Item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD1.** It appears this behavior is caused by New-Object cmdlet. If I replace it with [System.Collections.ArrayList] @() then I get what I need. Still I don't understand why it works this way.

Comment: What version of PowerShell? I'm unable to reproduce this behavior both in PowerShell 5.1, 7.0.3 and 7.1.0. Perhaps you're testing in a session with a previous version of your module loaded?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can reproduce it in 5.1 and 7.1. I updated the code in the question to clarify how the cmdlet is used. It is registered as a command in the Runspace, I am not using it in a module.

Answer (score 0):

The object is being passed to the cmdlet, but it is not being returned, i.e. `set` is called, but `get` is not. You'll need to return the collection via the pipeline and reassign it to the original variable. Here is the working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace CustomPowerShellCmdlet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string powerShellScript = @"
Write-Output ('PowerShell Version is ' + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion)

$A  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$A.Add('3') | Out-Null
Write-Output  ('Count is ' + $A.Count)

$B  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$B = (Add-CollectionItem -Collection $B -Item '1')
$B = (Add-CollectionItem -Collection $B -Item '2')
foreach ($Item in $B) {
    Write-Output $Item
}
Write-Output  ('Count is ' + $B.Count)
";
            var output = RunPowerShellScript(powerShellScript);

            foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static Collection<PSObject> RunPowerShellScript(string powerShellScript)
        {
            InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initialSessionState.Commands.Add(new SessionStateCmdletEntry("Add-CollectionItem", typeof(AddCollectionItemCmdlet), null));

            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;
                    ps.AddScript(powerShellScript);
                    return ps.Invoke();
                }
            }
        }

        [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "CollectionItem")]
        public class AddCollectionItemCmdlet : Cmdlet
        {
            [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
            [AllowEmptyCollection]
            public ArrayList Collection
            {
                get; set;
            }

            [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
            public object Item { get; set; }

            protected override void ProcessRecord()
            {
                Collection.Add(Item);
                WriteObject(Collection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well, visually it seems to do what I need, but behind the scenes it is still a copy of the collection. I slightly modified my code to include debug info. Regardless of the approach, it outputs ' A new collection is passed to the cmdlet: True
A new collection is passed to the cmdlet: True'

Answer (score 0):

It appeared this is a bug in PowerShell, see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14394